# Install RoR on debian Squeeze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

is there any way to install Ruby 1.9.2 or 1.8.7 + Rails 3 on my debian squeeze?

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't want to use RVM on a production machine. Its $PATH magic will break in non-obvious places (e.g. cron jobs), and you'll be up a creek.

You could simply build from sources and use checkinstall to create a .deb for yourself. Here's a [tutorial for Ubuntu](http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/ruby-1-9-2-on-ubuntu-11-04/) that should translate pretty well into debian.

Answer (score 3):

First install `rubygems`, I think it's the only Debian package. Then (as Ruby gems):

- `rvm` (install with it `ruby 1.9.2`, or Ruby version you want)
- `bundler`
- `rails`

And then you can manage application gems with Bundler.

Comment: I've installed rvm 1.9.2 successfully and when I try to write ruby -v, it tells me: "The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. To run 'ruby' please ask your administrator to install the package 'ruby'

Comment: You don't actually need to install a copy of Ruby to make RVM work - if you install GCC (build-essentials package) and Git (git-core package), then running the shell command specified on the RVM Website will do it. Then you can run "rvm install ruby-1.9.2" to get the latest version of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [railsready-debian-lenny](https://github.com/vysogot/railsready-debian-lenny) (it is claimed to work on Squeeze too)? Don't forget to install dependencies pointed in [readme.md](https://github.com/vysogot/railsready-debian-lenny/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

The steps below outlines installing Ruby On Rails as a normal user.

Check first if the user has sudo rights. To do this try executing a simple command

```
$sudo ls -a
[sudo] password for unlimit:
unlimit is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

If you see a message like above, you will need to add the user to the sudoer file, this can be done by

```
$echo 'unlimit ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

Check if you have ruby installed. Execute the command below

```
$ruby -v
-[bash]: ruby:command not found
```

If you see something like this, this means ruby is not installed. Install it

```
$sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Install additional libraries

```
$sudo apt-get install build-essential
$sudo apt-get install curl
$sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Install rvm

```
$curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Set the rvm path

```
$source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

You should add this to the .bashrc file.
Fetch the latest rvm and reload it

```
$rvm get head && rvm reload
```

Install ruby 1.9.3

```
$rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm.usr
```

I needed to install the readline lib

```
$sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Get the rails gem

```
$gem install rails -v 3.2.3
```

Check if you have rails

```
$rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
```

Get the readline package

```
$rvm pkg install readline
```

Get sqlite3

```
$sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

You are all set to create your first rails app

```
$rails new app HelloWorld
```

You can find more info http://unlimit.in/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-debian.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install Ruby and any Gems you like is with [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It will compile the latest version of Ruby for you and give you tools to manage gemsets.

Relying on the distribution's packages is usually a bad idea, because they are typically out-of-date.