# Is it possible to install Cucumber on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: cucumber, debian

I am trying to find out if Cucumber can be install on Debian Squeeze.  If so, I also need installation instructions including any pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108437/install-ror-on-debian-squeeze) for lots of helpful links for installing Ruby and Ruby Gems on Debian Squeeze.

Once you've done that, you can use the official [installation guide](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Install) to install Cucumber on top.